# Why supremum not max in definition of matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products

I know the definitions of max and sup. But, I don't see why would we use sup in this definition for example, rather than max.
[image]

This is definition of vector-induced norm of a matrix.

Comment: max is not well defined on infinite sets.

Comment: @DonThousand is this a rule? whenever you have an infinite set, you use sup? never max ?

Comment: @JohnDeterious The point is that for an infinite set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ you do not know that there is an element $x \in A$ such that $y \leq x$ for all $y \in A$ (that is that $x = \max A$ exists). However the $\sup$ exists for any such $A$, so you write your definition in terms of a $\sup$ and then argue that $\sup A \in A$ so that $\sup A = \max A$.

Comment: You can use max since you are in a finite dimensional setting; in the infinite dimensional, you have to put the supremum. You can still put maximum if you are in a _complete_ inner-product space (the so-called spaces of Hilbert).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, we use $\sup$ when $\max$ does not exists. However, in this particular case, when $n$ is finite, the set $\{x\in K^n:\Vert x\Vert=1\}$ is a compact set. Since the continuous function $\Vert Ax\Vert$ attains its maximum on a compact set, here $\max$ exists. Hence, $\sup$ and $\max$ are the same.

Comment: But - to add - this does not carry over (does not generalise) to infinitely-dimensional normed spaces, while the supremum definition does generalise. Thus it is probably better that people already see the supremum definition even in the finitely-dimensional case, in which the maximum does exist (and is thus equal to the supremum).